# XAMPP (WIndows) PHP GMP Functions

Tags: php, windows, xampp, gmp

Is there any way to use **PHP GMP Functions** on windows without using a virtual machine?

Thanks in advance.

[http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.ph]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to GMP's website:

**GMP's main target platforms are Unix-type systems, such as GNU/Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, Mac OS X/Darwin, BSD, AIX, etc. It also is known to work on Windows in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.**

Also try to uncomment `;extension=php_gmp.dll` in php.ini

Hope it works!

Answer (score 28):

Now, in XAMPP that uses PHP 7.2.4 comment has another format:

`;extension=gmp`

Uncommenting this will make it work also!

Comment: It woked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

According to GMP's website:

GMP's main target platforms are Unix-type systems, such as GNU/Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, Mac OS X/Darwin, BSD, AIX, etc. It also is known to work on Windows in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

Also try to uncomment

```
       ;extension=php_gmp.dll in php.ini
```

else uncomment

```
       ;extension=gmp in php.ini
```

**NOTE - Don't Forget to restart your server e+g - xampp otherwise the changes will not take effect**

Answer (score 0):

just add `extension=php_gmp.dll`  to end of  `php.ini` and restart your apache server .. it's work fine for me ..