# WebPush gmp extension is not loaded but is required for sending push notifications with payload . You can fix this in your php.ini

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, notifications, web-push

I am working on notification using webpush. i used [this](https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webpush) link to implement notificaton web push.I am searching and applying every solution from last week but same problem
I installed gmp and i added in xampp/etc/php.ini

```
extension = mcrypt.so
```

This is my code

```
class InvoicePaid extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $title, $body;
    public function __construct($title, $body)
    {
        //
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->body = $body;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [WebPushChannel::class];
    }

    public function toWebPush($notifiable, $notification)
    {
        $time = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        return WebPushMessage::create()
            // ->id($notification->id)
            ->title($this->title)
            ->icon(url('/push.png'))
            ->body($this->body);
        //->action('View account', 'view_account');
    }
}
```

My route is

```
Route::post('/send-notification/{id}', function($id, Request $request){
    $user = \App\User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\GenericNotification($request->title, $request->body));
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
});
```

But when i send notification i got this error

[image]

This is picture of gmp installation

[image]

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: make sure you have php-gmp installed and add this line to your php.ini: `extension=php_gmp.so`

Comment: kindly i installed php-gmp and also add line in php.ini .kindly tell me how cam i make sure i installed gmp?

Comment: restart your server. then create a file called `index.php` or `whateveryouwant.php` in your server root directory. Paste this code into that file: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Then navigate to `http://localhost/index.php` or `http://localhost/whateveryouwant.php` in your browser to check your php configuration settings. If you find `gmp` there, then it's installed.

Comment: GNU GMP support Stanislav Malyshev
this is info about gmp that i got after calling phpinfo()f

Comment: Okay. so that means your code should be working now. Are you still seeing an error?

Comment: Yes i am still getting same error . i am too much worried.

Comment: See if [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/429585/how-to-install-enable-gmp-math-functions-for-php-on-ubuntu) and [this for xampp on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448409/xampp-windows-php-gmp-functions) helps you.

Comment: but i have macbook

Comment: why would you then use an xampp? Try using Homestead for development, it has all extensions and other commonly used things: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead

Comment: @Mudassir Did you find the solution to this issue? I'm having the same issue and couldn't solve it at all. I researched everywhere but didn't get the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 18.04, PHP 7.4. Solved by following commands:

1. sudo apt install php7.4-gmp
2. sudo service php7.4-fpm restart

Comment: sudo apt install php7.4-gmp solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Try to go to your `xampp/php/ext` folder

- check if `php_gmp.dll` exists

  - open `xampp/php/php.ini`

    search for `php_gmp` and make sure it's like `extension=php_gmp.dll` instead of `;extension=php_gmp.dll`
- else

  - download `php_gmp.dll` to the folder and try the procedure again

You should not have gmp issue again.